# How to create 2 threads in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Currently trying to learn how to implement 2 threads where one does a summation and one does an average. I already have the summation function and average is just average = (sum/i). Do I need another function? And if yes, should it look exactly like the summation function but with just average = (sum/i)? Not sure where to go from here so let me know what else needs to be done.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum; /* this data is shared by threads */
void *runner(void *param); /*  the thread */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
pthread_t tid; 
pthread_attr_t attr;
{
if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
    /*exit(1);*/
    return -1;
}

if (atoi(argv[1]) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Argument %d must be non-negative\n",atoi(argv[1]));
    /*exit(1);*/
    return -1;

/* get the default attributes */
pthread_attr_init(&attr);

/* create the thread */
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, argv[1]);
pthread_t tid[2];

/* now wait for the thread to exit */
pthread_join(tid,NULL);

printf("sum = %d\n",sum);
}

/* the thread will begin control in this function */

void *runner(void *param)
{
int i, upper = atoi(param);
sum = 0;

    if (upper > 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= upper; i++)
            sum += i;
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
 }
```

Running into some errors now. Here's a screenshot of them. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sud4.png)

Comment: who is the doer of average part?

Comment: Consider posting code that will compile

Comment: My fault, i forgot to include "int main(int argc, char *argv[])". Currently doing this on a Linux VM and I can't just copy and paste the code.

Comment: You guessed right, you need to write further code. Just go ahead and try, if you managed to write the above code the second part should be a breeze.

Comment: I added a picture of some errors I'm not sure about above. If someone could help me that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very poor exercise because the second thread can't do anything before the first thread is complete. There's absolutely no point in using two threads.

Also, creating a thread just to perform a division is wasteful. It'll take longer to create and reap the thread than to do the actual operation.

The following program matches your specs. It uses one thread to do the sum, and a different thread (the pre-existing one) to do the average.

When all you need to pass to/from a thread is an integer, you can pass a `inttype_t` or `uinttype_t` cast to a `void*`.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t sum(uintptr_t i) {
   uintptr_t sum = 0;
   while (i)
      sum += i--;

   return sum;
}

void *sum_thread(void *param) {
   return (void *)sum((uintptr_t)param);
}

int main(void) {
   uintptr_t i = 5;

   pthread_t sum_thread_handle;
   pthread_create(&sum_thread_handle, NULL, sum_thread, (void *)i);

   uintptr_t sum;
   pthread_join(sum_thread_handle, (void **)&sum);

   printf("sum = %" PRIuPTR "\n", sum);
   printf("avg = %lf\n", ((double)sum)/i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The C standard only specifies that the conversion pointer --> u/intptr_t --> pointer results in the same value for pointer. It does not guarantee that u/intptr_t --> pointer --> u/intptr_t results in the same value for u/intptr_t

Comment: Although that's true, @alk, the technique presented for passing an integer to a thread via its start function's argument is widely used, and is reliable in practice on all implementations of which I am aware that support pthreads.  I'm uncertain at the moment whether POSIX demands it explicitly, but the large existing body of code that relies on it makes it a *de facto* requirement for implementations with pthreads.